# Tkinter, deselecting checkbuttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm quite new to Tkinter, I've made this script that creates a new window displaying what checkbutton you selected in the first window. The problem is, if you select one, then deselect it, it still shows it as checked. What would fix this? Thanks

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

global option1
global option2
option1 = 0
option2 = 0

master = Tk()

def getName():
    master.destroy()

def option1():
    global option1
    option1 = 1

def option2():
    global option2
    option2 = 1

def cb():
    global option1
    global option2
    window = Toplevel(master)
    if option1 == 1:
        titlelabel1 = Tkinter.Label(window, text="option 1", font =   ("calibri", 10, "bold"))
    if option2 == 1:
        titlelabel2 = Tkinter.Label(window, text="option 2", font = ("calibri", 10, "bold"))
    submit = Tkinter.Button(window, text ="Submit", command = getName, bg = "gray24", fg = "white")
    if option1 == 1:
        titlelabel1.pack()
    if option2 == 1:
        titlelabel2.pack()
    submit.pack()


titlelabel = Tkinter.Label(master, text="TICK BUTTONS", font = ("calibri", 18, "bold"))
option1 = Checkbutton(master, text="Option1", command = option1)
option2 = Checkbutton(master, text="Option2", command = option2)
submit = Tkinter.Button(master, text ="Submit",command = cb, bg = "gray28", fg = "white")
titlelabel.pack()
option1.pack()
option2.pack()
submit.pack()

mainloop()
```

***working solution***
Thanks for helping furas, I found a way, maybe not the simplest but,

`oddarray = [1,3,5,7,9]`
no one will click it more than 9 times?
Change the part in cb2 from option2 = 1 to,

```
option2 = option2 + 1
```

change if option1 == 1 and if option2 == 1: to,
`if option2 in oddary:`

Comment: don't use the same name `option1`, `option2` for global variables and functions (which create global variables too, so they overwrite existing variables).

Comment: Thanks, changed them but still having the same problem that once button2(option2) is clicked, even if unclicked, the variable option2 still equals 1.

Comment: problem is because you assign function which always set `option1 = 1`, you never do `option1 = 0`

Comment: you can use `option1 = False` and in function use `option1 = not option1` to change `False` to `True` and `True` to `False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in your function you always set `option1 = 1` and never do `option1 = 0`

You can use `False` instead of `0` and in function do

```
option1 = not option1
```

to change `False` to `True` and `True` to `False`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def change_option1():
    # you need `global` to inform function
    # to use external variable instead of local
    # because you will assign value
    global var_option1 

    var_option1 = not var_option1

def change_option2():
    # you need `global` to inform function
    # to use external variable instead of local
    # because you will assign value
    global var_option2

    var_option2 = not var_option2


def subwindow():
    # you don't need `global` 
    # because you will not assign value
    #global var_option1
    #global var_option2

    window = tk.Toplevel(master)

    if var_option1:
        tk.Label(window, text="Option 1").pack()

    if var_option2:
        tk.Label(window, text="Option 2").pack()

    submit = tk.Button(window, text="Submit", command=window.destroy)
    submit.pack()

# --- main ---

# it creates global variable so you don't need `global`
var_option1 = False
var_option2 = False

master = tk.Tk()

lbl_title  = tk.Label(master, text="TICK BUTTONS")
cb_option1 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Option1", command=change_option1)
cb_option2 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Option2", command=change_option2)
btn_submit = tk.Button(master, text="Submit", command=subwindow)

lbl_title.pack()
cb_option1.pack()
cb_option2.pack()
btn_submit.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Or you can use `Tkinter` special variables - `BooleanVar()`, `IntVar()`, `StringVar()` and then you don't need `command=` but `variable=`.

And you have to use `.get()` to get value and `.set()` to assign value

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def subwindow():
    # you don't need `global` 
    # because you will not assign value
    #global var_option1
    #global var_option2

    window = tk.Toplevel(master)

    if var_option1.get(): # you need get()
        tk.Label(window, text="Option 1").pack()

    if var_option2.get(): # you need get()
        tk.Label(window, text="Option 2").pack()

    submit = tk.Button(window, text="Submit", command=window.destroy)
    submit.pack()

# --- main ---

master = tk.Tk()

# it creates global variable so you don't need `global`
# It has to be after tk.Tk()
var_option1 = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
# or 
var_option2 = tk.BooleanVar()
var_option2.set(False)  # you need set()


lbl_title  = tk.Label(master, text="TICK BUTTONS")
cb_option1 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Option1", variable=var_option1)
cb_option2 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Option2", variable=var_option2)
btn_submit = tk.Button(master, text="Submit", command=subwindow)

lbl_title.pack()
cb_option1.pack()
cb_option2.pack()
btn_submit.pack()

master.mainloop()
```